# import package without specifying class

Tags: java, inheritance, import, multiple-choice

I've been given the following question from my lecture and told from him that the answer is `iii.It compiles, runs and prints the string “Hello”`however I believe the answer is  `i.  It has a compilation error` this is due to the way class B imports packA which is incorrect and instead should be import packA.A or packA.* 
my question is - is this a typo or can this still run and print "Hello"

```
   J.   Assuming the class A and class B given below are defined in different packages, packA and packB.

    package packA;
    public class A {
        protected void msg() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }

    package packB;
    import packA;
    class B extends A {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B obj = new B();
            obj.msg();
        }
    }


    which of the following is correct about the class B?

    i.  It has a compilation error
    ii. It has a run time error
    iii.It compiles, runs and prints the string “Hello”
    iv. None of the above
```

Comment: TRY IT YOURSELF.

Comment: WHY THE SCREAMING?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: I have tried it and I cannot run the program unless I specify "import packA.A" OR "import packA.*" in class B, yet I'm still unsure if this is absolutely correct, maybe my lecturer meant something else that I'm not quiet catching onto here? OR maybe I am right and this is actually a typo?

Comment: Depends Who do you trust more? The compiler or your professor?

Comment: Definitely the compiler, just checking to see if I'm missing something not obvious but it seems to be a typo at this point. Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a mistake in the import. It should be `import packA.A;`.

Comment: there is indeed a mistake in the code the import has to be packA.A

Comment: nevertheless thank you for taking your time to comment, appreciate it.